# Adding a Series of Fraction to the nth Power and Finding the Sum - C++

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that adds 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3......and gives the user the option to enter the nth term they would like it to go to. (between 2-10)

It needs to display the fractions (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8....) then find out their sum and display at the end. (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 = .96875)

I'm missing something crucial in my code and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting the fractions to show up multiple times before the program adds them together.

```
// This program displays a series of terms and computes its sum.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    int denom,              // Denominator of a particular term    
        finalTerm,    
        nthTerm;                 // The nth term
    double sum = 0.0;       // Accumulator that adds up all terms in the series

   // Calculate and display the sum of the fractions. 
   cout << "\nWhat should the final term be? (Enter a number between 2 and 10)";
   cin >> finalTerm;

   if (finalTerm >= 2 && finalTerm <= 10) 
   {   
        for (nthTerm = 1; nthTerm <= finalTerm; nthTerm++)
        {   
            denom = 2;
            while (denom <= pow(2,finalTerm))
            {   
                cout << "1/" << denom;
                denom *= 2;

                if (nthTerm < finalTerm)
                    cout << " + ";
                sum += pow(denom,-1);
            }   
        }   
        cout << " = " << sum;
   }   
   else
       cout << "Please rerun the program and enter a valid number.";

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have lost track of what each loop is supposed to *do*. What should the `for` loop do in one iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need for loop:

```
    // This program displays a series of terms and computes its sum.

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    int denom,              // Denominator of a particular term    
        finalTerm,    
        nthTerm;                 // The nth term
    double sum = 0.0;       // Accumulator that adds up all terms in the series


   // Calculate and display the sum of the fractions. 
   cout << "\nWhat should the final term be? (Enter a number between 2 and 10)";
   cin >> finalTerm;

   if (finalTerm >= 2 && finalTerm <= 10) 
   {   
        //for (nthTerm = 1; nthTerm <= finalTerm; nthTerm++)
        //{ 
            denom = 2;
            while (denom <= pow(2,finalTerm))
            {   
                cout << "1/" << denom;
                denom *= 2;

                if (nthTerm < finalTerm)
                    cout << " + ";
                sum += pow(denom,-1);
            }   
        //} 
            cout << " = " << sum << endl;
   }   
   else
       cout << "Please rerun the program and enter a valid number.";

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and I'm still getting several fractions added then it displays the sum and it does it several times. I just want it once. So there's something wrong in the body of my code that is making it repeat. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: @user2792977, what is the purpose of the for loop?

Comment: I was supposed to use a for loop as part of the exercise. I think I can do something more along the lines of what you suggested and just turn the while loop into a for loop. It seems like my variable "nthTerm" isn't really needed. I have my code so it's not repeating, but it's doing the math wrong, so I have to figure that out now.

Comment: Okay and that part was just because I had the denom *= 2 before the summation.